# Create a dynamic bootstrap table in Angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

Im trying to convert my current jquery code to angular js. There is a section of the code where a dynamic bootstrap table is create based on the json data received from the spring rest service. Below is the jquery code for creating the dynamic table.

```
$("#"+queryTableId).bootstrapTable({
                    cache: false,
                    data: queryTableContent,
                    toolbar: "#analysisEle_"+queryBtnId+"_"+QueryName,
                    toolbarAlign: 'right',
                    search: true,
                    pagination: true,
                    showColumns: true,
                    showToggle: true,
                    showExport: true,
                    exportDataType: 'all', // basic, all, selected
                    exportTypes: ['json', 'xml', 'csv', 'txt', 'sql', 'excel','pdf', 'doc'],
                    onClickRow: function (item, $element) {
                        $("#"+queryTableId).find('tbody tr.active').removeClass('active info');
                        $element.addClass('active info');
                    }
                });
```

I wanted to dynamically create the above bootstrap table using Angular js.  Need help in understanding how to convert the above to angularjs. Im mainly looking for the features being offered by the above table. I.e the column search, pagination,etc features offered needs to be available.

Any help on this is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The features would all be provided by the jQuery plugin you're using. Unless you're including the full version of jQuery (not generally recommended for Angular projects) then you'll likely need to find an alternative Angular plugin that matches the functionality you need.

Comment: Thanks chris for the update.Can you please elaborate the same. Can you please let me know how the table gets created using the jquery plugin. Also is there any way I can update the features like table size etc for the same.

Comment: That's not the sort of answer you should expect on this site. There's way too much functionality being provided by the current plugin for us to figure out what it's doing and to then give you instructions on how to do it. If you really want to build it yourself then I'd start by looking at the code for the jQuery plugin to see what it's doing, then learn how Angular works and build it up bit by bit. If I were you though I'd look for an Angular plugin that offers similar functionality instead. Will be a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

Search for an existing angular directive which can do the same work for you.

All dom manipulation should go through directives in angular.